# Stop file being compared in Pull Requests on GitHub

Tags: git

I have three branches (dev, stg, prd) on my GitHub project and I would like to keep the file dataform.json away from merges when new Pull Requests are opened.

The dataform.json file contains different values for each environment so that is why I don’t want to track changes but I need to keep the file on the branches to be able to run CI/CD pipeline.

I have tried many solutions found out there:

`git update-index —-skip-worktree` looks to work on git local but not when I create PRs on GitHub.

Comment: One approach is to consider having 3 files, perhaps like: `dataform.dev.json`, `dataform.stg.json`, and `dataform.prod.json`. Then run a script to copy the appropriate file to `dataform.json` for each env when it will be used (e.g. at build or deploy time). Those files can exist on every branch without issues.